# ASP.NET MVC: Unit Test EditorFor generates an empty MvcHtmlString

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nunit, visual-studio-2019

I'm working on MVC 5 project and I have an unit test that checks the generated html markup for a custom html helper.

```
private class Faq
    {
        [RequiredIfMultiple(new string[] { "SickLeave", "Holidays" }, new object[] { 2, 2 })]
        [RequiredIfMultiple(new string[] { "SickLeave1", "SickLeave2", "SickLeave3" }, new object[] { 2, 2, 2 })]
        public string Property { get; set; }
    }

[Test]
    public void HtmlString_With_RequiredIfMultiple_Test()
    {
        //Arrange
        Expression<Func<Faq, string>> expression = (t => t.Property);

        //Act
        IHtmlString result = htmlHelper.EditorForRequiredIf(expression);

        // Assert
        Assert.IsTrue(result.ToString().Contains("data-val-requiredifmultiple"));
    }
```

**The html helper extension EditorForRequiredIf**

```
public static MvcHtmlString EditorForRequiredIf<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper
        , Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression
        , string templateName = null
        , string htmlFieldName = null
        , object additionalViewData = null)
    {
        string mvcHtml = EditorExtensions.EditorFor(helper, expression, templateName, htmlFieldName, additionalViewData).ToString();            
        string element = helper.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression));
        string key = helper.ViewData.Model.ToString() + "." + element;

        if (RequiredIfMultipleAttribute.CountPerField != null)
        {
            RequiredIfMultipleAttribute.CountPerField.Remove(key);
            if (RequiredIfMultipleAttribute.CountPerField.Count == 0)
            {                    
                RequiredIfMultipleAttribute.CountPerField = null;
            }
        }

        string pattern = @"data\-val\-requiredif[a-z]+";

        return Regex.IsMatch(mvcHtml, pattern) ? MergeClientValidationRules(mvcHtml) : MvcHtmlString.Create(mvcHtml);
    }
```

Once in the view, the **EditorFor** calls *GetClientValidationRules* method on a custom attribute **RequiredIfMultipleAttribute** to generate the html markup with proper data-val tags.

**GetClientValidationRules** method:

```
public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        int count = 0;
        string key = metadata.ContainerType.FullName + "." + metadata.PropertyName;            

        if (CountPerField == null)
        {
            CountPerField = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        }

        if (CountPerField.ContainsKey(key))
        {               
            count = ++CountPerField[key];
        }
        else
        {
            CountPerField.Add(key, count);
        }

        yield return new RequiredIfMultipleValidationRule(ErrorMessageString, Props, Vals, count);
    }
```

So in production, all of this works perfectly. **But during tests**, I'm having an awful time.
What I get is an **empty string** on `string mvcHtml = EditorExtensions.EditorFor(helper, expression, templateName, htmlFieldName, additionalViewData).ToString();` and on the calls stack, I don't see the method *GetClientValidationRules* has been called.

On the other hand, if I change *EditorExtensions.EditorFor* by *InputExtensions.TextBoxFor*, I see that the MvcHtmlString is correctly generated and *GetClientValidationRules* was called.

**Does anyone have a clue?** and I hope I was clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

For the atttribute to work, some piece of code that executes your method has to recognize it and act on it in some way. When you are running your code in production that's what Asp.Net MVC does for you.

Your **test** is run by NUnit, not by Asp.Net. NUnit doesn't do anything with the attribute because it's not designed to do that. If you think about it, you'll realize that NUnit could not possibly recognize and act on all the various attributes known to all the hosts in which production code may run.

As a result, any use you make of that attribute has to be in your MVC application itself, not in your test.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance! But during the tests, I succeed to pass the test using _TextBoxFor_ but not with _EditorFor_.It is the difference in results which I didn't get!